# How can I do processing on every frame using Sceneform?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I want to update my data associated with anchors that are updated each frame.  How do I get the frame from ArSceneView for every frame?

Answer (score 5):

The ArSceneView updates the ARCore Frame object before drawing the scene.  You can access the frame by calling `getArFrame()` from a method registered with `setOnUpdateListener()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.sceneView = (ArSceneView) findViewById(R.id.scene_view);
    sceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener((this::onSceneUpdate));
}

private void onSceneUpdate(FrameTime updatedTime) {
    Frame frame = sceneView.getArFrame();
    Collection<Anchor> updatedAnchors = frame.getUpdatedAnchors();
    for (Anchor anchor : updatedAnchors) {
        // Handle updated anchors...
    }
}
```

Comment: How to record a video from ArSceneview?

Comment: @MathaN here is a Video Recording sample from Google in case you still need it https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/videorecording